# How am I getting spam with WSOD?

Tags: advertising, wsod

I get a small amount of spam email from my contact form, and haven't yet put a solution in place.

Recently got the wonderful WSOD (have fixed it since), and noticed i was STILL getting spam. Curious how this could still be happening, and if that means certain spam protection ideas may not work.

I was thinking of adding Antibot. Would this still work?

Comment: You should use [reCaptcha](https://www.drupal.org/project/recaptcha)

Answer (score 2):

The WSOD may have been caused by actually visiting your site, loading the page etc.. for example some block load error. Whereas the spam is probably sent directly to the form action by HTTP POST.

As mentioned already, recaptcha may be a good option there.